# What are vocal effects used by most of Norah Jones songs?

Tags: voice, logic-pro, effects

This question is mostly from sound production/synthesis/effects perspective. I would like to know how to achieve vocal effects usually heard in songs of Norah Jones. I am not sure how to describe it exactly so I have included a list sample songs. I'd say it sounds a little damp, short reverb like in small hall.

- Happy pills
- Flipside
- Thinking about you

Hope I am not sounding too vague.

Answer (score 2):

**Happy Pills** has a short 'slapback' delay on the vocals plus a subtle room reverb/ambience.

**Flipside** has some sort of compression on the vocals that add a tiny bit of breakup to the sound. This is combined with a stereo slapback delay (albeit subtle), and at times it sounds like the vocals are multitracked with subtle variances between the takes.

•**Thinking About You** Again a subtle slapback delay and some room ambience, but more monaural than the other cuts.